# Passing a wallet to rpcwallet in bitcoind JSON RPC

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I want to set a wallet as default wallet in the commands that run with `json-rpc` calls. the `-rpcwallet=blah` sets the `blah` wallet as the wallet which command will run on it; how can I simulate the similar thing with sending a JSON-RPC request?

When I sending the request, for example `curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getwalletinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/`, but it run on default wallet. how can I pass the wallet as a parameter in my request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To query a specific wallet, set the URL to be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/<wallet_name>
```